# Merge two images which were partially identical into one image

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

I want to merge several images of the same width into one long image, but these images may be partially identical. Is there some algorithm or documentation to introduce this thing?

[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0CTp.png)

Comment: Please correct the spelling in the heading and add more details, concrete problem, what's the literature you explored, and what do you expect from us as the answer?

Comment: Read opencv, it has some image stitching features.

Comment: Please try to explain your question more clearly. For example, will the resulting image be tall, or wide? Sample images?

Comment: This is a form of image stitching. I recommend you do some research on that topic.